# How to overload "operator %" in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, modulo

I want to overload the % operator in c++, in order to avoid editing a huge block of code by hand. I tried this:

```
static float operator %(const float& left, const float& right);
```

In my header, but it wont work because "nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type".
I'm relatively new to C++, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: You can't overload operators for fundamental types.

Comment: Can you please post what you were going to do within that function? I'm really want to learn how to perform the modulo operation on floats!

Comment: Well, that's sad. Just curious, what is the reason?

Comment: @ArniBoy: I almost just wanted to answer with "Because C++ is not Ruby", but perhaps you mightn't get that reference. :-)

Comment: @ArniBoy The reason is to prevent people from doing exactly what you're trying to do. Imagine if I overloaded `operator+` on ints to perform multiplication instead. Anyone including my header file with that in definition in it would be in for a wild ride.

Comment: @Chris: That's what I was thinking too.  Ruby is my favorite non-C++ language for that reason.

Comment: @Praetorian: That's precisely the kind of thing Ruby permits (by design), via monkey-patching. :-) C++, again by design, does not have monkey-patching. :-P

Comment: @Praetorian  Wouldn't there be a ambiguity conflict, as long as I'm not using namespace screwMath ? And there isn't even a defenition for float%float I'm overwriting! But okay, gotta google for Ruby now..

Comment: @ArniBoy: You realise there's `fmod` in `<cmath>` that does exactly what you want?

Comment: "Avoid editing code by hand" - most C++ IDE's have powerful Search&Replace options. You might need to write a regex, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Operator overloads must have at least one of their arguments as a user-defined type.  So you cannot do this.

Answer (score 3):

What that means is that you cannot overload an operator when all the operands are non-class/enum types. i.e., you cannot override the behaviour of `%` when both sides are `float` (or `int`, or any other primitive type).

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated, you cannot define overloaded operators for intrinsic types.

However, if you are willing to take advantage of implicit type conversion you can achieve something close to what you require with a single cast to one of your floats on a wrapper type that implements an overloaded% operator.

```
class FloatWrapper
{
private:
    float m_Float;

public:
    FloatWrapper(float Value):
      m_Float(Value)
    {
    }

    friend float operator%(const FloatWrapper& lhs, const FloatWrapper& rhs)
    {
        //your logic here...
        return (int)lhs.m_Float % (int)rhs.m_Float;
    }
};

int main()
{
float Value1 = 15.0f;
float Value2 = 4.0f;

float fMod1 = (FloatWrapper)Value1 % Value2;
float fMod2 = Value1 % (FloatWrapper)Value2;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
public:
     float operator%(float);
};
```

In C++ you need not to declare the operator as static, as opposed to C#. The argument can be of any type and the return value can also be. The first type would be the class itself.

Example:

```
Test test;
float x = test % 10.2f;
```

Comment: This is not really the same thing. There are two floats in the question.

Comment: Oops! By looking at `static` and two arguments, I thought OP is from C# world!